# Keep scrolling down while loading in cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, integration-testing, cypress, e2e-testing

I have a page that has an element where if you scroll down, it loads new data.

This takes about 10 seconds.

I have written the following test:

```js
it('Should display at least one facility in booking panel', (done) => {
  function recursivelyScroll() {
    cy.get(element)
      .scrollTo('bottom');

    cy.get(element)
      .then($el => {
        // If the element contains a loading class, we wait one second and scroll down again
        if ($el.find(Loading).length > 0) {
          setTimeout(recursivelyScroll, 1000);
        } else {
          // We are done waiting, no more loading is needed
          // write test here

          done();
        }
      });
  }
  recursivelyScroll();
});
```

> CypressError
>
> Timed out after `4000ms`. The `done()` callback was never invoked!

The `done()` method is not called fast enough according to Cypress, but they have no documentation on how to extend the `done` time period. Also, there might be a better way that I'm unaware of to create this scrollbehaviour in Cypress. Is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the recursion plugin in cypress?

It would look something like this:

```
cy.get(element).scrollTo('bottom');
recurse(
    () => cy.contains('element', 'Loading').should(() => {}),
    ($quote) => $quote.length > 0 ,
    {
      limit: 300,
      log: false,
      post(){
        setTimeout(recursivelyScroll, 1000);
      }
    },
)
```

The idea was taken here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHn7647xOz8
Here example how to use and install https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-recurse

Comment: This looks promising! I stepped away from the tests that required this code but I really like this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch to When assertion and declare that function outside the execution:

```
When('Should display at least one facility in booking panel', (done) => {
    recursivelyScroll(done)
}

function recursivelyScroll(done){
    //see implementation below
}
```

Not sure how about which "Loading" is, maybe you have to put into double quotes?

Moreover please note that cypress is asynchronous, then the scrollTo and the then code sections are executed at same time in your code, just use then after the scroll.

And I will change the setTimeout into cy wait function before executing recursion, give a try to below code:

```
function recursivelyScroll(done) {
    cy.get(element)
    .scrollTo('bottom')
    .then($el => {
        // If the element contains a loading class, we wait one second and scroll down again
        if ($el.find(".Loading").length > 0) {
            cy.wait(1000).then(()=>{
                recursivelyScroll(done);
            })
        } else {
            // We are done waiting, no more loading is needed
            // write test here
            done();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The `cy.wait` might be what I needed to do instead of `setTimeout`, this also looks promising. The Loading is a variable in my code so there is no need for me to change the rest, but I understand that it's hard to reproduce this way. Thx for the suggestion!